# In C++, can you use a dot (.) in variable or function names?

Tags: c++

When making variables, function, and class names can you include a dot (.) in the name?

Comment: What happens when you try?

Comment: Thank you everybody for your nice responses! I am still learning c++ so this helps a lot!

Comment: Dot is used to accessing members.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An identifier consists of letters, digits, or the underscore (where the first character is not a digit).  A dot is not allowed.

Answer (score 7):

No, a dot (.) is reserved only for references to functions or variables from a class. You only can use these:

```
 _ a b c d e f g h i j k l m
n o p q r s t u v w x y z
A B C D E F G H I J K L M
N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

The number characters are allowed as any character in an identifier except the first

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/565w213d.aspx

Answer (score 2):

No.  A dot (.) is only used to reference a member of an instance of a class/record.

Comment: For example, to access the "first" member of the integer 3, say `3.1` :-)

Answer (score 1):

C++ variable identifiers can only include alphanumeric characters and the underbar ( _ ). They have to begin with a letter (not a number).

For example

Allowed:

```
int my_variable;
char myVariable2;
string my2ndVariable;
```

Not allowed:

```
double 2ndvariable;
```

There are also some words that are reserved for system use, so you can't use those as variable names either (one example being 'friend').

Variable names are also case sensitive (i.e. you can declare `int IVAR` and `int iVar` and `int iVAr`, etc.) You can also use the same exact identifier for two different variables as long as they are of different datatypes (i.e. you can declare `int myVariable` and `char myVariable`).

Similarly, you can have functions with the same name as long as they include either a different datatype for the return variable or different parameters (this is called function overloading). A function's signature is comprised of it's return datatype, it's identifier, and it's parameters, as long as one of those elements is different the signature will be different, so you can still do it.